# Why does $\sqrt{3}x^2-4\sqrt{3}=0$ not follow discriminant rules?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, discriminant

From what I understand:

$D > 0$ and a perfect square $\Longrightarrow$ Real and Rational Roots

$D > 0$ but not a perfect square $\Longrightarrow$ Real and Irrational Roots

$D = 0$ $\Longrightarrow$ Double Root

$D < 0$ $\Longrightarrow$ Complex Roots

My question is that the discriminant of $\sqrt{3}x^2-4\sqrt{3}$ $\Longrightarrow$ 48

48 is not a perfect square yet the roots for $\sqrt{3}x^2-4\sqrt{3}=0$ are real and rational.

Comment: Not sure about the "perfect square" and rational claim. By the quadratic formula (here with $b=0$): $x = \dfrac{\pm\sqrt{-4ac}}{2a}$, and both the numerator and denominator are irrational. Then the roots happen to be rational this time, but no guarantee.

Comment: @peterwhy My teacher just said the rule is if the discriminant is a perfect square then the roots are real and rational.

Comment: And you found a counterexample.

Comment: @peterwhy So it's not a universal rule?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect, I'm afraid. It tells you nothing about the rationality of the roots, but whether the roots are real or complex, and about their multiplicity

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Thanks I was just a little confused because of what my teacher stated this as a fact but I guess there are exceptions

Comment: Was your teacher perhaps talking about $ax^2+bx+c=0$ when $a=1$?

Comment: I've seen teachers over-reach for theorems and I've seen students misunderstand what the teachers are saying.  The teacher's comments, as you have written them, are correct when $a,b,c$ themselves are rational.  That's probably all they were saying.

Comment: @TedShifrin you can simplify it so that a = 1 and that doesn't change the discriminant and I think he just stated it was a general rule

Comment: @OxPh This depends on what you define as the "discriminant".  Using the common definition I've seen, "simplifying it so that $a=1$" changes the discriminant.  (but even in that case, if you let either of $b,c$ be non-rational, you'll find yourself in the same trouble again)

Comment: The rules about the discriminant as you stated is typically  intended for rational coefficients. Because in High school, that is typically what they are.....but of course, wit irrational coefficients one can still have rational solutions as you indicated.  I will go even one step further: You can have rational solutions with COMPLEX coefficients!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My teacher just said the rule is if the discriminant is a perfect square then the roots are real and rational"

That rule is for polynomials with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how
$$\sqrt{3}x^2- 4\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3} (x^2-4)$$
As such the roots of the polynomial (i.e. the solutions to $\sqrt{3}x^2- 4\sqrt{3}=0$) have to be the same as $x^2-4=0$

If you want to find a rule for the solution to be rational given a quadratic equation
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0
$$ is that
$
\frac{D}{4a^2}$ is a perfect square, $\frac{b}{2a}$ is rational and $D\ge0$. Indeed the roots of a second degree polynomials are
$$
x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{2a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{D}{4a^2}}
$$
As you can prove from the usual formula

I want to clarify that this is a sufficient condition, but is not necessary, as *e.g*
$$x^2+(1+\sqrt{2}) x + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=0$$
does not satisfy this condition (you can check that $D=2$), but still has a rational root.

Comment: That factoring of that radical is really smart for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$ whose coefficients are real numbers, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq 0$.

Then we can rewrite it as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = ax^{2} + bx + c\\\\
& = a\left(x^{2} + \frac{bx}{a} + \frac{c}{a}\right)\\\\
& = a\left[\left(x^{2} + \frac{bx}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4a^{2}}\right) - \left(\frac{b^{2} - 4ac}{4a^{2}}\right)\right]\\\\
& = a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2} - \frac{\Delta}{4a}
\end{align*}

Hence we split the behavior of $f$ into three cases:

- If $\Delta > 0$, then $f$ has two (distinct) real roots.
- If $\Delta = 0$, then $f$ has two (equal) real roots.
- If $\Delta < 0$, then $f$ has no real roots.

As you have noticed, $\Delta = 48$ when $f(x) = \sqrt{3}x^{2} - 4\sqrt{3}$.

Then we may conclude that $f$ has two distinct real roots.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You really cant comment on roots being rational or irrational for D>0 .

roots are given by -b +- sqrt(b^2-4ac) /2a

Even if the D is perf square roots being rational/irrational depend on b and a

Like in your question the a=sqrt3 so the sqrt3 in D is cancelled by the a=sqrt3.